# How do I use a variable in an array name in PHP? (variable arrays/variable variable?)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've looked at other questions/answers but I'm not fully understanding it. Furthermore, I haven't found one asking my exact question.

I have 7 arrays storing the start and end times for a business. My PHP program checks for the current day and matches it with the start end time for that day. So right now I have 7 `if` statements similar to this:

```
if (date(l) == 'Sunday') {
   $start = $SundayAccountingHours['start'];
   $end = $SundayAccountingHours['end'];
 }
```

What I want to do is clean up the code. So maybe I could have something like

```
$start = ${$today}.AccountingHours['start'];
$end = ${$today}.AccountingHours['end'];
```

How can I make this work? Using the above example I'm getting this: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dev.php on line 22** where line 22 is $start is defined. I can't take out the stuff in the brackets because THAT'S the information I need to really get to.

If you can't tell, I'm still novice at PHP so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: the `.` in php is not an property operator but instead a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (date(l) == 'Sunday') {
   $start = $SundayAccountingHours['start'];
   $end = $SundayAccountingHours['end'];
 }
```

First, put quotes around that `'l'`. It's looking for a constant named `l`, and failing to find that it's treating it like a string. This is very bad practice (and should issue a warning).

Secondly, use a multi-dimensional array. You don't need to try and use the day-of-the-week as part of your variable name. e.g.,

```
$start = $AccountingHours[$today]['start'];
```

You might discover variable-variables down the road which allow you do something like what you're trying, but I strongly advise you to steer clear of them. I don't think there's a single practical application for them and they only serve to cause confusion and error ([*cough*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682648/65387)).

Answer (score 1):

If you MUST use variable variable names (You should really go for multi-dimensional arrays though), try something like this.

```
$start = ${$today.'AccountingHours'}['start'];
```

Comment: This is a case of solving the apparent problem, not the actual problem.

Comment: Completely agreed. Which is why I wrote the first line. :)

Comment: I will try to wrap my head around multi-dimensional arrays then. When I echo $start using your code, nothing is showing up. It's like the variable is empty...

Comment: Try `var_dump($SundayAccountingHours)` to see if the variable is being generated at all. This is actually one of the main problems with using variable variables. The code becomes very difficult to debug.

Comment: Thank you @AshwinMukhija, that helped me narrow down my problem. It was NULL and I realized it was because I changed something earlier today before doing this. Turns out it was a capitalization problem.

Comment: I do agree that multi-dimensional arrays would be the correct answer to this problem. However, I am marking this as the accepted answer because it actually answered the question I asked. I WILL not be using this method in the final version of my program though.

Answer (score 0):

Array elements can be referenced by variables like so:

```
$myArray[$myVar]
```

Arrays can also contain other arrays, like so:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray['a'] = array();
$myArray['a']['b'] = 'foo';
print $myArray['a']['b'];  // prints 'foo'
```

So combine the two concepts and you can create a multi-dimensional array referenced by variables:

```
$accountingHours = array();
$accountingHours['Sunday'] = array('start' => ..., 'end' => ...);
// ...
$start = $accountingHours[$today]['start'];
```